# What would cause a water pressure drop after tripping a breaker?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, water-pressure

I recently plugged my laptop into a cheap powerbar, which caused said-powerbar to short. This tripped the "sockets" circuit on the breaker, which, upon resetting, caused power to begin flowing to stuff again (Namely the hot water heater).

Only problem is, now I have low pressure for both hot and cold water. A tap was running when the short happened, and the pressure immediately dropped out. I live in a ~15 year-old forth-storie flat in the UK, with a [basic indirect plumbing system](http://www.hartons.co.uk/pdfs/PlumbingsystemA.pdf) and separate [condensing wall hung system boiler](http://www.centralheating.co.uk/system/uploads/attachments/0000/2966/Minima_HE_System.pdf).

Any idea what might be causing this, and what I need to reset (Bonus marks for "How")?

**Update:** After a day and a half, the pump or whatever came back to life and there's now water pressure. Leaving question open in case anyone has an idea about what was causing the problem, and any way of possibly fixing it.